# How signal is propagated to child processes in an entrypoint script of a Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, shell

In my `Dockerfile` I have

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/opt/run.sh"]
```

In `run.sh`

```bash
env LOG_FILE=/opt/log/p1.log java -jar ./app.jar
```

If I create a container and `exec` into it and run

```bash
ps -a -o pid,pgid

PID  PGID
1    1
7    1
```

now, while still in the container if I run

```bash
kill -s 15 1
```

The java app will not receive the signal BUT if I send the signal to process group id

```bash
kill -s 15 -1
```

The java app receives the signal.

My understanding is when `run.sh` is creating a child process (java -jar) in the foreground when the script receives a signal it should propagate the signal to its children but in my case it does not, why?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/